# Sitecore launchpad appearing when I open preview window for french version

Tags: sitecore-client

I am using sitecore 8.2 initial version. Sitecore launchpad window appearing when I am trying open it for french version of item. It's working fine for english. Anyone experience same issue?

Comment: Check the logs . Is thre any error which forces the page redirect to launchpad page. Also , check the network tab to see if there is any 302 redirect.